# Ubuntu 11.10 won't install Nginx due to dependecy failure (libssl1.0.0)

Tags: nginx

I keep getting this error when I ask *apt-get install nginx-full*

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 nginx-full : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) mais 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.7 devra être installé
```

It's in French and I cannot find the exact equivalent in English but it says that a dependency is unsatisfied (?) and that 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.7 should be installed.

I have tried apt-get update, upgrade, nothing works.

Comment: It's better to use official packages: http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html

Answer (score 9):

This seemed to work for me

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

(This is downloading the package from [this website](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb.html).)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

to install the lib of ssl.

Comment: it says it's already the last available version I have installed